# Unable to register extra fileds in a pivot table using sync function with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pivot-table, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I'm unable to register extra fields in a pivot table:
This my scheme:

[image]

**Buyer Model:**

```
public function qualities(){
    //many-to-many relation
    return $this->belongsToMany(Quality::class);
}
```

**Quality Model:**

```
public function qualities(){
    //many-to-many relation
    return $this->belongsToMany(Quality::class);
}
```

**Product Model:**

```
public function buyers(){
    //many-to-many relation
    return $this->belongsToMany(Buyer::class);
}
```

Before of send the data to the `sync` function, I'm combining the data:

```
 public function store(createBuyerRequest $request){
        if($request->validated()){
          try{
            //Register buyer
           $buyer = new Buyer;
           $buyer->ruc = $request->ruc;
           $buyer->companyName = $request->companyName;
           $buyer->contact = $request->contact;
           $buyer->address = $request->address;
           $buyer->phone = $request->phone;
           $buyer->email = $request->email;
           $buyer->save();
           
           $arrayQualitiesIds = $request->get('qualitiesProductCheckbox');
           
           //Build arrayMap

            $extra = array_map(function($qualityId) use($request){
                return ['quality_id' => $qualityId, 'product_id' => $request->product];
            }, $arrayQualitiesIds);
            // Combine the array
            $data = array_combine($arrayQualitiesIds, $extra);
      
            $buyer->qualities()->sync($data);

            return redirect()->route('admin.buyers.index')
            ->with('status_success','Comprador registrado correctamente!');
          }catch(Exception $e){
        
               return redirect()->route('admin.buyers.index')
             ->with('cancel','No se pudo registrar el comprador. '.$e->getMessage());
          }
        }
    }
```

The output of `$data = array_combine($arrayQualitiesIds, $extra)` of one example was this:

Output:

```
1 => array:2 [▼
    "quality_id" => "1"
    "product_id" => "5"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "quality_id" => "2"
    "product_id" => "5"
  ]
  3 => array:2 [▼
    "quality_id" => "3"
    "product_id" => "5"
  ]
```

The combination was successfully done! however was unable of register the data in the pivot table, only was registered the buyer.

This is view from the form to register a buyer:

[image]

Basically a buyer is being registered and selection a product of interest and his qualities.. The business wants register a buyer with his desired product.

The code `$buyer->qualities()->sync($data);` should register the `buyer_id` automatically using the relation and fill the pivot table with array combination putted in `$data`.

Any Idea for fix this problem guys I will appreciate, thanks so much.

**Fixed**

I just modified the relation inside of the `Buyer` model:

```
  public function qualities(){
        
            return $this->belongsToMany(Buyer::class, 'product_interested','quality_id', 'product_id','buyer_id')->withTimestamps();;
        }
```

I also needed of add the `buyer_id` inside of the `array_map`:

```
 $extra = array_map(function($qualityId) use($request, $buyer){
                return ['quality_id' => $qualityId,
                         'product_id' => $request->product,
                         'buyer_id' => $buyer->id];
            }, $arrayQualitiesIds);
            //combine arrays
            $data = array_combine($arrayQualitiesIds, $extra);
            /*
            dd($data);
            array:1 [▼
            4 => array:3 [▼
              "quality_id" => "4"
              "product_id" => "6"
              "buyer_id" => 19
            ]
          ]
            */
            $buyer->qualities()->sync($data);
```

I don't know the reason why `$buyer->qualities()->sync($data)` not inserted automatically the `buyer_id`

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the name of the pivot table in your relation methods like this:

Buyer Model:

```
public function qualities(){
    //many-to-many relation
    return $this->belongsToMany(Quality::class, 'product_interested');
}
```

Comment: You have to specify that in all your relationship methods related to pivot table.